# What is the minimum Android version supported by Butterknife?

Tags: android, butterknife

I am adding the [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library to my Android application. What is the the minimum Android version it works well on, or does it work well with all versions of Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minSDK is 14. Check it here - https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/build.gradle

```
 ext.versions = [
  'minSdk': 14,
  'compileSdk': 27,

  'supportLibrary': '27.0.2',
  'androidPlugin': '3.0.1',
  'androidTools': '26.0.1',
  'kotlin': '1.2.10',

  'release': '8.8.1',  ]
```

And usage here:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/build.gradle

Comment: checked it. I think it's 9,  minSdkVersion = 9?